# Performance conscious way to deserialize messages into various types dynamically

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, types, protocol-buffers

I am writing a networking application. In the interest of speed and efficiency, I've decided to use simple length-prefixed, serialized messages. I looked into a few, namely protobuf, but ended up settling on [ZeroFormatter](https://github.com/neuecc/ZeroFormatter)

My messages look like this:
`[[length][header][serialized message contents]]`

I am having trouble figuring out an elegant way of *deserializing* the messages, however.

Obviously, I could have some function that basically does:

```
IMessage message;

  switch (message.Type)
  {
      case 1:
          message = new MessageOne(...)
          break;
      case 2:
          message = new MessageTwo(...)
          break;
      default:
          Console.WriteLine("Unknown message type");
          break;
  }
```

But I expect to have at least 100 different message types. This makes for an extremely ugly `switch`.

I tried creating a method that would dynamically produce a message, and learnt a hard lesson in compilation (cant use `system.Type` as a generic type...):

```
var messageTable = new Dictionary<int, Type>();

populate the dictionary with types...

public bool TryParse(byte[] buffer, out IMessage message)
{
    Type msgType = messageTable[buffer[0]];

    message = ZeroFormatterSerializer.Deserialize<msgType>(buffer.Skip(1)); <== Obviously cant do this with generics...
}
```

Also tried using static functions on `Type` variables...

```
var messageTable = new Dictionary<int, Message>();

populate the dictionary with types...

public bool TryParse(byte[] buffer, out IMessage message)
{
    Type msgType = messageTable[buffer[0]];

    message = msgType.Serializer.Deserialize(buffer.Skip(1)); <== Obviously cant do this with static methods...
}
```

I *absolutely* want to avoid expensive things like `Reflection`. The server will handle many messages per second (hopefully!).

I feel like I'm missing something... I realize that, being completely metadata-less, these messages require descriptors on either end of the wire. That is not a problem, I will have full control over the code on either end.

How can I approach this keeping performance *very much* in mind?

Comment: On first read of your post, I am tempted to think that you might confuse some terms: "Deserialize" is converting a message back to a typed instance in your language (class). And your switch case code, that addresses the problem of "message dispatching". If you want to transmit packages with multiple message types over a channel, sometimes you need to create your own "protocol header", which can be as easy as define a class with 1 property for each message type you trade.

Comment: `cant use system.Type as a generic type...` Why?? I use it constantly...

Comment: Seems like ZeroFormatterSerializer.NonGeneric could solve your problem

Comment: @user1242967 It sure does... Can't believe I missed that! I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it is easy to miss when there are no real docs for the library :)

Comment: @user1242967 Actually, I think this just moves my problem somewhere else. With the `NonGeneric`, I can deserialize to `Object`, but i'll run into the same issues getting that `Object` to whatever `Type` the message should be. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dynamic Funcs at the begining of your code, store them in a dictionary and then use those.

```
Dictionary<byte, Func<byte[], IMessage>> converters = 
                                        new Dictionary<byte, Func<byte[], IMessage>>();

public void CreateConverter<T>(byte Id) where T : IMessage
{
    converters.Add(Id, (byte[] Data) => ZeroFormatterSerializer.Deserialize<T>(Data.Skip(1)));
}

public IMessage Deserialize(byte[] Data)
{
    return converters[data[0]](Data);
}

//Somewhere on your initialization code...
CreateConverter<0, MessageOne>();
CreateConverter<1, MessageTwo>();
//...

//Now you can simply do
IMessage msg = Deserialize(Data);
```

Also, I would avoid as much as you can the `Skip` part, it's an IEnumerable extension and those are slow, if the deserializer supports it use an `ArraySegment` skipping that byte, else I would test if creating a new array and using `Buffer.BlockCopy` is faster than using `Skip`.

Even further this can be expanded to be fully automatic with this:

```
//Modify IMessage
public abstract class IMessage
{
    public abstract byte Id{ get; }
}

//Add the property to your messages
public class MessageOne : IMessage
{
    public override byte Id{ get{ return 0; } }
}

//Create a Init method

void Init()
{
    var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IMessage)));
    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("CreateConverter");

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var instance = (IMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        genericMethod.Invoke(this, instance.Id);
    }

}

//Now you only need to do at the begining of your code...
Init();
```

Comment: This seems *very* elegant. I like it a lot. It even makes it very easy to modify how `converters` are created. I am curious about your comment though... Are you saying that I could do `Type type = typeof(SomeClass)` then do `new Dictionary<type, int>()`???

Comment: Wait a second, I'm expanding this to be automatic.

Comment: Here you go @MatthewGoulart

Comment: About the generic, look at the code I added to init, look how it can be used. Yes, it's through reflection, but if you prepare everything beforehand the reflection impact is very reduced.

Comment: I'm having difficulty with `MethodInfo method = typeof(this).GetMethod("CreateConverter");` What is the context? (what is `this`)?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart `this` is the class where the function `CreateConverter` is coded (I assumed all the code is in the same class).

Comment: Sorry, It's wrong, use `typeof(classTypeHavingCreateConverter)` or `this.GetType()`. @MatthewGoulart I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, this code runs *once* at the beginning of the app, dynamically makes the `CreateConverter` function on *all* classes implementing `IMessage`, then *calls* that same function in order to create the "converter function". **Nevermind, I got it**

Comment: Yes, you got it right. But no, there's no need to add the `genericMethod`s to a dictionary as there will be one different per each class type and will be used only once on the `Init` function, the call to the generic method creates the `Func` and adds it to the dictionary @MatthewGoulart

Comment: Thanks very much. This seems like a great solution. I'll give it a try!